# Discord.py bot cannot invite user to guild

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot instantly dm any user that gets kicked from a guild with an invite. It always says "TypeError: on_member_remove() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'" I do not know how to mitigate this issue. Any help would be appreciated

```
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(guild,user):
    link=await create_invite(guild)
    await user.send(link)
    print("invited kicked user")
```

Comment: Looks like `on_member_remove()` has one only argument: `member`-  https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_remove#discord.on_member_remove -

The examples show how to deal with a member joining. Maybe members leaving could be handled in a similar way? https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/new_member.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `on_member_remove` has only one argument - `member`. If you want to create invite link you need to get channel (example: TextChannel) and call function `create_invite` for this channel. Example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)  # Your channel
    invite = await channel.create_invite() # Create invite link
    await member.send(invite)              # Send link to user
```

Comment: When I test this, it says that name "CHANNEL_ID" is not defined

Comment: Channel id is id of your channel, just copy it and set instead of CHANNEL_ID